# need to craft a regex matching a string in a url while excluding ending string

Tags: nginx, regex

I'd appreciate some help with crafting the right regex for an nginx map block please. Essentially, I need a match a pattern [typically a word: such as course] in a url but url must not end in extensions such as jpg, png, gif

so while it should match:

> /course/history

it should not match:

> - /course/history.png
> - /course.jpg
> - /course/history/student/boy.png

I simply can't get any thing to work, feels like I'm far from it

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri_course {
~/course/+ !.(jpg|png|gif)$   http://www.example.com/courses;
}
```

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

For example:

```
~^/course/[^?]*(?<!\.(jpg|png|gif))([?]|$)
```

---

Alternatively, considering that regular expressions are evaluated in order, you could use two statements, with the first evaluating to zero.

For example:

```
~\.(jpg|png|gif)([?]|$)    0;
~^/course/               /some/path;
```

Comment: many thanks. That seemed to have worked, The second option suits my use case better. Thanks again